# Laravel query fiter review in with relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
$listing = Listing::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)
->with('reviews')
->with('posts')
->get();
```

How can i filter review order when i try this

```
 ->whereHas('reviews', function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'Public');
        })->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
```

I want am trying to use orderBy on review but when i try orderBy on review its filter post also but i do not want to post so please Help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply more filters in the whereHas functon, but to apply more conditions like ordering and limiting you should do that in the with function call on the correct relationship you will be loading.

```
$listing = Listing::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)
    ->with(['reviews' => function ($query) {
        return $query->orderByDesc('created_at');
    }, 'posts'])
    ->whereHas('reviews', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('status', 'Public');
    })
    ->orderByDesc('created_at')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think you code is right but i have summery of listing and in this summery all post and all reviews 
and i pass parameter like ?review=desc or ?post=desc when filter its shorting both data
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
$listing = Listing::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)
->with(['reviews','posts'])
->whereHas('reviews', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'Public')->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    })
->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
->get();
```

Comment: I think you code is right but i have summery of listing and in this summery all post and all reviews 
and i pass parameter like ?review=desc or ?post=desc when filter its shorting both data
Thank you